Which scope should be used in AppIdentifyService API of GCP to access workflow APIs?
 public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataDeletionWorkflowService.class.getName());
    public static final String WORKFLOW_HOST = "workflowexecutions.googleapis.com";
    public static final String HOST = "host";
    public static final String BEARER = "Bearer";
    private final NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    public NetHttpTransport getNetHttpTransport() {
        return netHttpTransport;
    }

 public static String generateOIDCToken() {
        ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>();
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
        final AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
        return appIdentity.getAccessToken(scopes).getAccessToken();
    }

 public String getToken() throws IOException {
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = generateOIDCToken();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Token: {0}", token.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error getting token", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return token;
    }
    
public void sendWorkflowUpdate(String callbackUrl, Object payload) throws IOException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sending workflow update to: {0}", callbackUrl);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Payload: {0}", payload);
        String jsonPayload = gson.toJson(payload);
        String token = getToken();
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getNetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
                .setAuthorization(String.format("%s %s", BEARER, token))
                .setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .set(HOST, WORKFLOW_HOST);

        HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(
                new GenericUrl(callbackUrl),
                new ByteArrayContent(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, jsonPayload.getBytes()));
        request.setHeaders(headers);
        request.setThrowExceptionOnExecuteError(true);

        try {
            request.execute();
        } catch (HttpResponseException exception) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error sending workflow update", exception);
            if (exception.getStatusCode() != 429) {
                throw exception;
            }
        }

    }

Is the scope used the correct one to access google workflow apis (cloud-platform)?  The scope used is not landing the request in the workflow api call back url.
Is the implementation correct the http request is not reaching the workflow callback.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Your question is not a minimal repro making it more difficult for us to help. What did you do exactly? What specific errors did you observe? All (most?) of Google's Cloud (Platform) services use IAM for authorization and use the general-purpose auth/cloud-platform[.read-only] OAuth scope.
